# What is the meaning of the も particle in this sentence?

Tags: particles, particle-も

> 短大を卒業した**のちも**就職せず、フリーター生活に甘んじていることを指しているわけではない。

I think のち means "later" here, like あと, but I don't understand the meaning of も here. Please, could you clarify for me?

Comment: In this particular instance, も in のちも is redundant and can be replaced with のち. It's beyond me how to grammatically explain the function of も here, but as a native Japanese speaker, I feel like this も works as a sort of buffer, a letter that has no meaning attached but that possibly indicates some implied meaning without revealing nothing about what is implied anyway.

Comment: @user48754 Isn't も emphasizing that the speaker wasn't looking for a job exactly when you'd expect the speaker to be?

Comment: IMHO, I don't think so. も is basically meaningless, just adding a subtle, blurred sense of impliedness. No expectations or emotions are suggested in も. Meanwhile, from the context, it is unclear whether the speaker themselves is the person who is the 就職していないフリーター or not. On a pedantic point, 短期 in the sentence should be corrected as 短大 or 短期大学, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, も has the effect of including the marked element in the same category as other similar or related things. Those "other things" are not always explicitly stated and are sometimes hard to identify. Your example is one of those cases.

However, technically speaking, も still includes the time frame of 短大を卒業したのち in the same category as at least one other time frame. The most likely candidate is 短大を卒業する前. You might think it's obvious this person doesn't find a (full-time) job while she is still in junior college, but that doesn't matter. It still serves the purpose of creating a contract in which 短大を卒業したのち is emphasized.

As a result, this も carries the sense of "even".

> 短大を卒業したのち**も**
> **even** after graduating from junior college

---

[EDIT]

The question, as I see it, is basically about what is different between 短大を卒業したのち就職しない and 短大を卒業したのち**も**就職しない and the latter *does* emphasize the fact whoever is the subject of this clause doesn't get a job after graduating from college, something the former states in a pretty neutral fashion. Why would they emphasize it? That's precisely because, as A.Ellett suggested, you are expected to look for a job after graduating from college (unlike when you were still in college) but you still don't. The translation with "even" is not that off. Whether to add も to 短大を卒業したのち or 就職 is a matter of choice, but I don’t see why they would use も at all unless they intend this emphasizing effect.